# RXJS concat: Ensuring logic in pipe executes before observable completes

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

From: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat

> Subscribe to observables in order as previous completes
>
> You can think of concat like a line at a ATM, the next transaction (subscription) cannot start until the previous completes!

Given the above I'd expect the following example to log as 1, '2', '3', 4. When I run this I'm getting 1, 4, '3', '2'. Is there a way to ensure the piped logic has run before completing?

```
import { concat, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const o1o2 = of(console.log('1')).pipe(map(x => console.log(2)));
const o3 = () => console.log(3);
const o4 = of(console.log('4'));

concat(o1o2, of(o3()), o4).subscribe();
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bqr9pr?file=index.ts

---

Edited:

In the above 1 and 4 were fired immediately when the lines were executed (before even hitting concat).

3 was fired because (of) creates a hot observable where logic happens before the observable returns. Similar scenario as above actually. As concat chains the observables before executing sequentially, so we see 3 logged. Defer is a way to make the observable cold.

2 was the only thing that was dependent on a subscription to log.

```
o4 = of(console.log('wut')).pipe(tap() => console.log(4))
also3 = defer() => {
    console.log(3)
    return of()
}
o3 = defer(() => {
    return of(console.log(3))
})
o2 = of(null).pipe(tap () => console.log(2))
o1 = of(null).pipe(tap () => console.log(1))

concat(o1, o2, o3, o4);
```

The below example would log
wut, 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this line-by-line:

---

```
const o1o2 = of(console.log('1')).pipe(map(x => console.log(2)));
```

When you call `of` on this line, you immediately evaluate `console.log('1')` and pass the result of the `log` function to `of` (the result of `log` is `undefined`).

**This logs `'1'` to the console.**

---

```
const o4 = of(console.log('4'));
```

Again, you are immediately evaluating `console.log('4')` and passing the result of that function, `undefined`, as the first argument to `of`

**This logs `'4'` to the console.**

---

```
concat(o1o2, of(o3()), o4).subscribe();
```

On this line, you are invoking `o3` immediately and using the result of that function as the first argument for `of`. As `o3` calls `console.log(3)` and returns its result, you are simply invoking `of()` with `undefined`.

**This logs `3` to the console.**

---

```
const o1o2 = of(console.log('1')).pipe(map(x => console.log(2)));
```

And we're now back to this line, which is, I think, the only one that is behaving as you were expecting because `x => console.log(2)` is a function, so it doesn't evaluate `console.log` until it's called. I don't know the RXJS library well, but since your second `log` call is wrapped in a function, it appears that `concat` is evaluating it while doing whatever it is that `concat` does.

**This logs `2` to the console.**

Comment: Thanks. Looks like defer would make o3 cold and have it work intuitively